# Twitter Bootstrap - thumbnails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I'd like to display thumbnails in the following configurations (from widest screen width to narrowest):

- 6 thumbnails across one row (each thumbnail is `span2`)
- 3 thumbnails across one row above another row of 3 thumbnails
- 2 thumbnails across one row above two other rows with 2 thumbnails each
- 1 thumbnail each row above 5 other rows with 1 thumbnail each

I want this to all be using the same mark up. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. Right now, I have something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
         ...
         ...
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

All this does right now is display 6 thumbnails across one row. When the screen width is too narrow, it changes layout to one thumbnail per row. It skipped the intermediate steps I wanted.

How do I achieve what I'm trying to do in TB? I'm hoping for a mark up only solution as I want to fully utilize what TB has to offer.

Comment: Create a fiddle with [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/) and we can try debugging it.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not possible just using markup and the bootstrap library. You'll have to write some CSS of your own to supplement the bootstrap media queries.

Comment: You have to define your own breakpoints with media queries. Bootstrap will rearrange columns on mobile only (`max-width: 767px`).

Comment: As an illustration of the suggestions above, see this question [link](http://bit.ly/VtSPeM)